# How to connect truffle contract with ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I have made a lottery contract and now I want to connect it to the front-end which I will create with ReactJS. I have used Truffle framework for the deployment and tests for my contract.

Answer (score 0):

```
      npm i @truffle/contract
```

Then in utils/loadContract:

```
import contract from "@truffle/contract"

export const loadContract = async (name, provider) => {
  // in truffle, contracts are in "contracts" directory
  const res = await fetch(`/contracts/${name}.json`)
  const Artifact = await res.json()
  const _contract = contract(Artifact)
  _contract.setProvider(provider)

  let deployedContract = null
  try {
    deployedContract = await _contract.deployed()
  } catch {
    console.error("You are connected to the wrong network")
  }
  return deployedContract
}
```

Then load the contract inside app.jsx. First:

```
  npm i @metamask/detect-provider
```

then write your code inside app.js

```
import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider'
import { loadContract } from "./utils/load-contract";
import {useEffect, useState } from "react";

// in useEffect I load this state. So when your component is loaded, you would have access to web3Api.contract to call the contract methods
 const [web3Api, setWeb3Api] = useState({
    provider: null,
    isProviderLoaded: false,
    web3: null,
    contract: null
  })

 // call this function inside useEFfect, if user connects to different account, you will update it
 const setAccountListener = provider => {
    provider.on("accountsChanged", _ => window.location.reload())
    provider.on("chainChanged", _ => window.location.reload())
  }

// useEffect is called before your component loaded
// load the contract, set the state, so when your compoent loaded, your state will be ready
useEffect(() => {
    const loadProvider = async () => {
      // if Metamask installed, this will detect its provider
      const provider = await detectEthereumProvider()
      // load the contract if provider exists
      if (provider) {
        // Lottery is not name of the file, it is NAME OF CONTRACT
        const contract = await loadContract("Lottery", provider)
        setAccountListener(provider)
        setWeb3Api({
          web3: new Web3(provider),
          provider:provider,
          // Now you set the contract. 
          // when your app.js loaded you will be able to call contract methods
          contract:contract,
          isProviderLoaded: true
        })
      } else {
        setWeb3Api(api => ({...api, isProviderLoaded: true}))
        console.error("Please, install Metamask.")
      }
    }

    loadProvider()
  }, [])
```

Comment: how do I access functions of my contract through reactJS?

Comment: if u check the `useState({
    provider: null,
    isProviderLoaded: false,
    web3: null,
    contract: null
  })` I loaded contract inside `useEffects`. so `web3Api.contract.methodName`